# JTextField: avoid display "," in numbers

Tags: java, swing, floating-point, jtextfield, value-of

I'm looking for a better solution than the one I currently have:

I have a textfield for which I read and right numbers in:

```
textStiffness.setText((""+stiffness).replaceAll(",", ""));
```

and

```
stiffness = Float.valueOf(s1.replaceAll(",", "")).floatValue();
```

and her you can see my problem and my work around:
When I write a number over 999 it adds a "," sign that then can't be read by the Float.value(s) method.

any ideas ?

Jason

Comment: No, I can't see your problem because you didn't post a SSCCE (http://sscce.org). What does "writing a number" mean? When you type a number into a text it doesn't automatcally insert a comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your needs, I think you should use a [JFormattedTextField](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html) for a clean solution. Have a look at this [tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) .